# Creating live stream using Kaltura CE and Red5

Tags: centos, red5, kaltura

I am trying to do a Live Streaming using FMS as mentioned in the link below:

```
http://knowledge.kaltura.com/live-streaming-using-kaltura-live-streaming-hds-hls-dash
```

I followed all the steps as mentioned in this link and when I generate the xml file to pass it to FMLE application, it does generate the xml file but for server name it generates `@PRIMARY_MEDIA_SERVER_HOST@` which is wrong.

After reading the steps carefully I found that, for Kaltura CE we need to do some additional steps as mentioned under link `How to integrate Kaltura CE 4.0 with Red5`.

```
http://blog.kaltura.org/rtmp-vod-and-live-streaming-using-red5-and-kaltura-ce-4/
```

As per the first step of this link i need to modify file `/opt/kaltura/app/alpha/config/kConfLocal.php` but I am having Kaltura CE 10.0.0 version and I am not able to find this file on my server.

Is it that this link is not valid for the latest version of Kaltura CE and we don't need to follow these steps, but what about `@PRIMARY_MEDIA_SERVER_HOST@` problem?

** **UPDATE** **

My `/opt/kaltura/app/configurations/broadcast.ini` file:

```
domain = mykaltura.com:80

[0]
domain = @PRIMARY_MEDIA_SERVER_HOST@
application.default = kLive
application.LIVE_STREAM_ONTEXTDATA_CAPTIONS=kLiveOTD

[1]
domain = @SECONDARY_MEDIA_SERVER_HOST@
application.default = kLive
application.LIVE_STREAM_ONTEXTDATA_CAPTIONS=kLiveOTD
```

Is this file Ok or do I need to change anything in it?

Comment: can you please  tell me what changes you have made for this ? I am stuck and need your help

Answer (score 1):

Try looking in /opt/kaltura/app/configurations/broadcast.ini

Comment: Thanks for the replay, What exactly I need to change in `broadcast.ini` file? I have updated question with my `broadcast.ini` file contains.

Comment: I have updated the `domain` and `application.default` in `broadcast.ini` file and with this change when I generate the XML file and use it in the FMLE then, I am able to stream from the FMLE, but somehow I am not able to see the stream in KMC, When I open live entry in preview mode.